# Vim Script trigger function on moving in insert mode but not on inserting characters

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I have a function that needs to be ran whenever the cursor moves in Insert mode, but not if it moved due to inserting a character.

The function should run on backspace-deleting, on inserting newlines, on moving around with the arrow keys. It should not run on inserting any character other than a newline, including spaces and symbols.

Is it possible to write such an `if` clause leveraging the `CursorMovedI` event?

Comment: Maybe you can `:inoremap` the `<Left>`, `<Right>`, `<Up>`, `<Down>`, `<cr>`, `<PageUp>`, `<PageDown>`, `<Home>`, `<End>`, and `<bs>` keys instead?

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).